# Default Cell Editor Class Query?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

This is how my `JTable` is reconstructed from the serialized data:

```
table = new JTable(){
    public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return true;
    }
};
table.addMouseListener(this);
table.addFocusListener(this);
int width = HCAConstants.hcaGuiFuzzyTableWidth;
int tableRowHeight = HCAConstants.hcaGuiFuzzyTableRowHeight;
table.putClientProperty("cancelEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
table.setModel(new MBFTableModel(data[currentH.Int][currentF.Int]));
TableColumn col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
col.setPreferredWidth(width);}
table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
    .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0), "none");
table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
    .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK), "none");
table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
KeyStroke tab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0);
InputMap map = table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
map.put(tab, "selectNextRowCell");
table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
    .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "none");
table.setEnabled(true);
table.setDefaultRenderer(FuzzyDat.class,new FuzzyDatRender());
table.setDefaultEditor(FuzzyDat.class, new FuzzyDatEditor(currentF,(LoadToTable)this)); 
table.setDefaultRenderer(MinMax.class, new MinMaxRender());
table.setDefaultEditor(MinMax.class, new MinMaxEditor());
table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
table.setRowHeight(tableRowHeight);
```

My Scenario is this: Whenever I click on the cell's slider for the first time, it does not respond; on the second click, the component responds and thereafter the slider responds to the first click.

How can make the slider interactive with the first click only rather than clicking twice initially.

The [`DefaultCellEditor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html#clickCountToStart) has three default constructors: `JCheckBox`, `JComboBox` and `JTextField`; but I need to override this constructor for `JSlider`. How can I achieve this? Is this necessary? It was suggested that I use `setClickCountToStart(1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe one of `SliderColumn` or `SpinnerColumn` may help:

SliderColumn:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.EventObject;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class SliderColumn extends AbstractCellEditor
    implements TableCellEditor, TableCellRenderer {

    private JSlider editSlider, renderSlider;
    private Border originalBorder;

    public SliderColumn(JTable table, int column) {
        editSlider = new JSlider();
        renderSlider = new JSlider();
        originalBorder = editSlider.getBorder();
        editSlider.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).setCellEditor(this);
        Dimension d = renderSlider.getPreferredSize();
        table.setRowHeight(d.height);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return editSlider.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        if (value != null) {
            editSlider.setValue((Integer) value);
        }
        return editSlider;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            renderSlider.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));
        } else {
            renderSlider.setBorder(originalBorder);
        }
        if (value == null) {
            renderSlider.setValue(0);
        } else {
            int intValue = ((Integer) value).intValue();
            renderSlider.setValue(intValue);
        }
        return renderSlider;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject evt) {
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("SpinnerColumn");
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
                JTable table = new JTable(5, 1);
                SliderColumn spinnerColumn = new SliderColumn(table, 0);
                table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, spinnerColumn);
                panel.add(table);
                frame.setContentPane(panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

SpinnerColumn:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.EventObject;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class SpinnerColumn extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, TableCellRenderer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JSpinner editSpinner, renderSpinner;
    private JTable table;
    private String[] list;
    private Border originalBorder;

    public SpinnerColumn(JTable table, int column) {
        editSpinner = new JSpinner();
        renderSpinner = new JSpinner();
        originalBorder = editSpinner.getBorder();
        editSpinner.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));
        this.table = table;
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).setCellEditor(this);
    }

    public SpinnerColumn(String[] list, JTable table, int column) {
        editSpinner = new JSpinner();
        editSpinner.setModel(new SpinnerListModel(list));
        renderSpinner = new JSpinner();
        originalBorder = editSpinner.getBorder();
        editSpinner.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));
        this.list = list;
        this.table = table;
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).setCellEditor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return editSpinner.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
            int row, int column) {
        if (list != null) {
            editSpinner.setValue(list[0]);
        } else {
            editSpinner.setValue(0);
        }
        if (value != null) {
            editSpinner.setValue(value);
        }
        return editSpinner;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            renderSpinner.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));
        } else {
            renderSpinner.setBorder(originalBorder);
        }
        // *** here's where we set the spinner's value
        if (value == null) {
            renderSpinner.setValue(0);
        } else {
            int intValue = ((Integer) value).intValue();
            renderSpinner.setValue(intValue);
        }
        return renderSpinner;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject evt) {
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("SpinnerColumn");
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
                JTable table = new JTable(5, 1);
                SpinnerColumn spinnerColumn = new SpinnerColumn(table, 0);
                table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, spinnerColumn);
                panel.add(table);
                frame.setContentPane(panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a `JSlider` variation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether either of `FuzzyDatRender` or `MinMaxRender` derive from [`JSlider`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html). It's not clear whether either of `FuzzyDatEditor` or `MinMaxEditor` have a `clickCountToStart` property similar to or derived from that seen in [`DefaultCellEditor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html#clickCountToStart). Without an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe, I don't see how to answer the question.

Addendum: After editing the question, I'm guessing that extending `AbstractCellEditor` would be better than `DefaultCellEditor` in order to avoid the default `clickCountToStart` value.

Comment: Derived from what? Which renderer? Which editor? Please clarify your question.